# Electron - Close initial window but keep child open

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am coding an electron app which is supposed to load a splash screen, and then open a new window. Afterwards the splash screen should be closed.

However I am not able to do that. In my `index.js`, the startup script, I have the following code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

app.on("ready", () => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({ /*...*/ });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash/splash.html`);
    win.on("ready-to-show", () => { win.show(); });
    win.on("closed",        () => { app.quit(); });
});
```

In `splash.html` I load the `splash.js` by using

```
<script>require("./splash");</script>
```

And in splash.js I tried the following code:

```
const remote = require("electron").remote;

let tWin = remote.getCurrentWindow();

let next = function(){ 
    let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({ /*...*/ });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main/main.html`);
    win.on("ready-to-show", () => { win.show(); });
    win.on("closed",        () => { app.quit(); });

    tWin.close();

    // I could just use win.hide(); here instead 
    // of tWin.close(); but that can't really be the right way.
};
```

The function `next()` gets called after a timeout. The problem is, if called, the main window shows up for a second but both, slpash and main close instantly.

I tried to fix that by commenting out

```
win.on("closed", () => { app.quit(); });
```

in my `index.js`. But that led to the following error:

> Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released.

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Attempting to call a function in a renderer window that has been closed or released. Function provided here: splash.js:38:9.
    at BrowserWindow.callIntoRenderer (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/browser/rpc-server.js:199:19)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at BrowserWindow.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent the newly created window from closing?

Comment: why do you want to load splash screen in another window. Dont you like that code?

Comment: you should load 'splash' and 'main' window in the same process, then show/hide depending on the events you need, I'll post an answer with my code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use a diferent approach. Here's how a use do it:

1. create global var reference for the main window and the splash window, if not it will be self closed by the garbage collector.
2. load '***splash***' browserwindow
3. on '*show*' event I call a function to load '***main***' window
4. on ***main*** window '*dom-ready*', I close '**splash**' and show '**main**'

Here's one example of my ***main.js*** electron code, feel free to ask:

```
   'use strict';

    //generic modules
    const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require('electron');
    const path = require('path')
    const url = require('url')

    const config = require('./config'); //                              => 1: archivo de configuracion
    const fileToLoad = config.files.current ? config.files.current : config.files.raw;
    const jsonData = require(fileToLoad); //                            => 2: archivo de datos (json) 
    const pug = require('electron-pug')({ pretty: true }, jsonData); // => 3: pasamos datos ya tratados a plantillas pug/jade 


    // Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
    // be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
    let win, loading
    app.mainWindow = win;

    function initApp() {
        showLoading(initPresentation)
    }

    function showLoading(callback) {
        loading = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, frame: false })
        loading.once('show', callback);
        loading.loadURL(url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/src/pages/loading.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }))

        loading.show();
    }

    function initPresentation() {
        win = new BrowserWindow({
            width: 1280,
            height: 920,
            show: false,
            webPreferences: {
                experimentalFeatures: true
            }
        })
        win.webContents.once('dom-ready', () => {
                console.log("main loaded!!")
                win.setMenu(null);
                win.show();
                loading.hide();
                loading.close();
            })
            // Emitted when the window is closed.
        win.on('closed', () => {
            // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
            // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
            // when you should delete the corresponding element.
            win = null
        })
        win.loadURL(url.format({
            //pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/src/pages/home.pug'),
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/lab/pug/index.pug'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true
        }))

        win.webContents.openDevTools() // Open the DevTools.
    }

    // This method will be called when Electron has finished
    // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
    // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
    app.on('ready', initApp)

    // Quit when all windows are closed.
    app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
        // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
        // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
        if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
            app.quit()
        }
    })

    app.on('activate', () => {
        // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (win === null) {
            initApp()
        }
    })

    // In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
    // code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.*/
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much! It works like a charm :)